# How to fit CSS flex contents within its width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 `DIV` components where:

- `.child-left`: aligns its contents to the left on the screen
- `.child-center`: aligns its contents to the center on the screen
- `.child-right`: aligns its contents to the right on the screen

However, when the contents (or text) get really long in `.child-center`, the contents overflow each other even though it has its own `width`.  Please see the below screenshot:

[image: example]

I'd like to know:

1. Why the content (`Long text...`) in `.child-center` does not fit within the width?
2. How do I fix the issue with the **minimal** changes? (I'd like to keep using `display: flex`, **I DO NOT want to use `text-align: center`**)

What I want to achieve is this:

[image: the goal]

Please help me out!

Code:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.child-left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-left">
    <span>11111111111111111111111111</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child-center">
    <span>Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child-right">
    <span>22222222222222222222222222</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the width on your flex children

Comment: @dalelandry Thanks for the reply! That doesn't solve the issue because removing the `width` increases the `.parent` width (now the horizon scrollbar is visible). I want to keep the child DIVs' width in a certain value, which is percentage for now

Comment: THen add a flex wrap on the child elements or remove the nowrap on white space as you are forcing a width for content that has no other option but to overflow. You could also add an overflow hidden which would hide the content.

Comment: remove justify-content:center and use margin:auto on child

Comment: @dalelandry I see, so basically it's impossible to achieve what I want with the option `white-space: nowrap`. Thanks!

Comment: @KimchiMan But **what exactly** do you want to achieve? Try to define expected behaviour on paper - what browser should do with your blocks when there is not enough space? How do you expect to both keep content in 3 blocks without wrapping and at the same time fit the container?

Comment: @VladislavAkhmetvaliyev Thanks for the reply! I've updated the question (attached the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz0vz.png). Please check it out!

Comment: @KimchiMan `span {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}` should work

Comment: @VladislavAkhmetvaliyev Thanks for the help! Can you add your solution as an answer, please?

Comment: @KimchiMan I can not as someone marked your question as duplicate. I can not even flag it to the moderator. Weird...

Comment: @VladislavAkhmetvaliyev I see, but your solution `max-width: 100%` solved my problem. Thanks thanks thanks!!!